# How was logarithm discovered?

Tags: calculus

How was the concept of $\ln(x)$ found before the man knows that it is the area under hyperbola or it is related to the power of $e$ (base of logarithm). How did Napier compute the value of $e$ or $\ln(x)$ before the concept of power of numbers was used in math?

Comment: See  Florian Cajori's 7-part series of papers [*History of the exponential and logarithmic concepts*](https://www.google.com/search?q=archive.org+%22History+of+the+Exponential+and+Logarithmic+Concepts%22) in **American Mathematical Monthly**, Volume 20 (1913), pp. 5-14, 35-47, 75-84, 107-117, 148-151, 173-182, 205-210.

Comment: Before the invention of the logarithms, long multiplications used to be performed by the prosthaphaeresis method, based on the product-to-sum trigonometric formulas. In fact, these were already logarithms, but in the imaginary domain ($e^{ia}e^{ib}=e^{i(a+b)}$).

Comment: Powers of numbers were known long before Napier.

Comment: See Brian Rice & Enrique González-Velasco & Alexander Corrigan, [The Life and Works of John Napier (2017, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=zdJNDgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: If the concept of power of numbers were known before Napier,there were no use for it unless it is applied in logarithm

Comment: See also this: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/42/which-came-first-the-natural-logarithm-or-the-base-of-the-natural-logarithm/47#47