# Who discovered Napier's number?

Tags: mathematics, euler

Who discovered Napier's number?

I read Bernoulli calculated it, Napier discovered it but it is e because of Euler.

I know how Bernoulli calculated it but where did Napier see it?

Comment: Napier did not "see" it, he (or rather his translator Oughtred) calculated some logarithms to base $e$ without needing the base itself. Several other people calculated related numbers before Bernoulli, but none of them isolated $e$, see [MacTutor's history of $e$](http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/e.html).

Comment: Napier used an approximate value. See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/42/which-came-first-the-natural-logarithm-or-the-base-of-the-natural-logarithm/47#47